# unable to set overlay div for block grids in foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Hey guys i am working on this gallery.
Now I've thumbnails set on block grid and ive added an overlay div on first list item and the problem is that i am not able to set it dynamically i mean 100 percent width and height because the gallery is responsive so what i wanted is that overlay should fix on thumbbs.

i am unable to set the fiddle so i am uploading a live example.
you can see overlay extending  thumbs.
please suggest a solution
[**Link**](http://beautifulsoftwares.com/test/)

Thanks.
***I need overlay on every thumb.***

Here is my Code new one

```
 <style>
    .thumbsList li {
      position: relative;
    }
    .overlay
    {

      position: absolute;
      z-index: 22;
      background-color: black;
      opacity: 0.6;
      height:100%;
      with:100%;
      z-index: 22;
    }  
  </style>

</head>
<body>  



 <div class="row projectsRow">

  <ul class="large-block-grid-3 medium-block-grid-3 small-block-grid-2 thumbsList">
    <li >

      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <img class="projectsThumbs" src="img\projects\1.jpg" alt="">

    </li>
    <li >
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <img class="projectsThumbs" src="img\projects\2.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li >
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <img class="projectsThumbs" src="img\projects\3.jpg" alt=""></li>




      </ul>

    </div>



    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>


  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Give a `position: relative;` to the your `<li>` elements. Also put the `<div class="overlay"></div>` tag inside each `<li>` tags.

```
.thumbsList li {
    position: relative;
}
```

And put the following code inside all `<li>` instead of just the first one.

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: i need overlay on every thumb and not a simgle overlay.

Comment: Hey Saikth its not working either. can we make a fiddle on foundation here?

Comment: maybe i am not able to set it properly. can you make me a fiddle pelase. If i do oerlay position to ablsoute, it spans the entire ul.

Comment: Did you change the `li` `position` to `relative`?

Comment: ive updated my question with a sample code. Please check if i am giving css to overlay class right or wrong?

Comment: Can you check my fiddle

Comment: @Saihn thanks it worked. it i have any problems i will surely ask you. thanks.

Comment: its till not 100%. when i do 100% it fills the screen

Comment: sure give me some time

Comment: updated my code online. when i do 100% the stuff goes crazy :(

Comment: By `crazy` do you mean the overlay is not matching the image width/height ?

Comment: yeah overlay is spannig the whole divs. and not just the image. see my example.

Comment: I had to add a span (`position:relative`) which will enclose both `image` and `div`. This way the `div` will be exactly same as `image`

Comment: The width (100%) and height (100%) include the padding. This is the problem.